# Clojure: How to Expand Varargs into List for Java Method

Tags: java, clojure, variadic-functions

I am working on a clojure function which accepts a variable number of arguments, and passes those to a java method call

```
(defn foo [var1 var2 & vars]
    (let [bar (.foo var1)]
        (.gaz bar var2 vars)))
```

This works when vars is empty, but when I put something in vars, I get

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast clojure.lang.ArraySeq to [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

It seems like the vars arent being spliced / interpolated into a vararg list to the method call.  How can I do this?  I want to use this as both

```
(foo a b)
```

and

```
(foo a b c d e f)
```

And have it calling

```
(.gaz bar b c d e f) ;; <- note the list is embedded
```

Comment: what do you mean by "expand into a list" - convert? separate out of a sequence into positional arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

note this this returns exactly the type your error message is asking for:

```
user> (into-array Object [1 2 3])
#<Object[] [Ljava.lang.Object;@571bc284>
```

From context, I assume `.gaz` is likely varargs. If so, all you need is the following:

`(.gaz bar var2 (into-array Object vars))`

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm.  I'm not sure I fully understand why it works but I will read up on into-array

Comment: The argument needed for varargs is expected to be a Class that a normal Clojure persistent collection does not implement. By converting to a more primitive, mutable Class, we satisfy the jvm's requirements.